# UnsupportedOperationException from Netbeans JSP

Tags: sql-server, netbeans, jdbc, datasource

I am creating a web based application using the following specs:
Glassfish server 3.1.1
- SQL Server 2012 Express
- Netbeans 7.01
- JDK 1.7
- JDBC Driver for Sql Server 4.0

I have created a Connection Resource and Connection Pool and can sucessfully ping the pool from the glassfish admin web interface. I then created a data resouce (Data source) in the xml file for the connection pool.

To test the data resouce i create a test JSP outside of the WEB-INF folder and add a DB report using the data source created in the previous step.

I receive the following error when running the test JSP:

TYPE: Exception report

MESSAGE:

DESCRIPTION: The server encountered an internal error () that precented it from fulfilling this request.

EXCEPTION:
org.apache.jasperException: java.lang.unsupportedOperationException: This operation is not supported.

ROOT CAUSE:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This operation is not supported.

I have spent the past 2-3 days searching the web for solutions but all of the examples i can locate provide aditional details/error codes after "This operation is not supported" in the exception description.

I have checked glassfish and they do not provide aditional details on the above error.

Hopefully somebody has had this same issue and was able to resolve the issue.

Here is the stack trace:

```
INFO: RAR7114: Unable to get ClientInfo for connection 
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This operation is not supported.
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.setClientInfo(SQLServerConnection.java:2890)
            at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionHolder40.setClientInfo(ConnectionHolder40.java:322)
            at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionHolder40.close(ConnectionHolder40.java:530)
            at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.QueryTagSupport.doFinally(QueryTagSupport.java:278)
            at org.apache.jsp.test.newjsp_jsp._jspx_meth_sql_query_0(newjsp_jsp.java:126)
            at org.apache.jsp.test.newjsp_jsp._jspService(newjsp_jsp.java:68)
            at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
            at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
            at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
            at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
            at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
            at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Any Help will be appriciated. I am to the point where i would use another connection method if anyone has a recomendation. Thanks!

The JSP test.jsp. I will be creating classes from views that exist in the database so the sql will be relatively simple from the JSP. The report is a test to make sure that the JSP can communicate with the sql server database.

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>
<%-- 
Document   : test
Created on : Jan 11, 2013, 8:06:27 PM
Author     : Developer
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <sql:query var="result" dataSource="jdbc/TestAddOn">
        select * from tblCustomer
    </sql:query>

    <table border="1">
        <!-- column headers -->
        <tr>
        <c:forEach var="columnName" items="${result.columnNames}">
            <th><c:out value="${columnName}"/></th>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
    <!-- column data -->
    <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rowsByIndex}">
        <tr>
        <c:forEach var="column" items="${row}">
            <td><c:out value="${column}"/></td>
        </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The XML reference

```
<resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/TestAddOn</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

the glassfish resource xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
  <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/TestAddOn" object-type="user" pool-name="TestAddOnConnectionPool">
    <description/>
  </jdbc-resource>
  <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="TestAddOnConnectionPool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:sqlserver://Localhost:1433;databaseName= MyDatabaseName"/>
    <property name="User" value="*******"/>
    <property name="Password" value="*******"/>
 </jdbc-connection-pool>
</resources>
```

Comment: Post the full stacktrace

Comment: Stack trace is now posted

Comment: Post the query tag too, and any other SQL tags that relate to it. It's happening on close, which is curious.

Comment: The JSP, XML and Glassfish XML is now posted. Thank you EJP and Mark for the help so far.

Comment: Look like the JDBC driver misbehaves with getClientInfo() and that Glassfish doesn't handle that well. I believe (but am not certain) that this was fixed in Glassfish 3.1.2 (issue [GLASSFISH-17061](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-17061); requires login to view)

Comment: Thanks, I will be testing with Glassfish 3.1.2 tonight and will let you know how it went.

Comment: I have downloaded Glassfish 3.1.2 and updated my project to use 3.1.2 but the admin councel is still showing version 3.1.1. Im working to correct the issue but wanted to provide an update. Hopefully i can actually begin writing java soon!